# Transmission/IOR Issue

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I don't know if it's a bug or eevee just can't handle multiple layers of transmission.
Basically I have two tubes. The inner Tube's transmission is 1. The outter tube's transmission also is 1.
To imitate a flow effect I animated the IOR of the inner tube. But if I "wrap" the outter tube around the inner tube the "flow" effect is gone. Transmission still work but not the IOR. I thought I might need to solidify the outter tube but thats not it.
[image: IOR GONE]
Regards

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the unavoidable drawbacks of using EEVEE. Transparency through transparency is barely supported - there are instances where you can make it work, but "tweaking settings" is largely hindered. Compared to Cycles, it can be very difficult if not outright impossible to get similar, photorealistic results with both multiple transparencies and the correct level/angle of refraction.

Comment: Thank you very much for that fast answer. thats too bad - i did a small work around by using the clearcoat. but its definately not the same.

Comment: Yeah. Like I said, depending on the scene, sometimes you can "fake it" well enough, but sometimes you definitely can't. If you find something that works for your scene that's all that matters.

Comment: Try blend method: hashed?